# Using the Neo4jrb gem, is it possible to use one transaction across multiple blocks

Tags: trailblazer, neo4jrb

Using the [neo4jrb/neo4j](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j) gem (8.x), I know it is possible to run multiple queries inside a single transaction like so

```
person = Person.find_by(id: person_id)

Neo4j::ActiveBase.run_transaction do |tx|
  person.update(name: 'New name')
  person.update(number: 1)
end
```

But it possible to open a transaction, and then use that same transaction across multiple blocks. Something like:

```
person = Person.find_by(id: person_id)

transaction = Neo4j::ActiveBase.new_transaction

transaction.run do |tx|
  person.update(name: 'New name')
end

transaction.run do |tx|
  person.update(number: 1)
end

transaction.close
```

The reason why this functionality is desirable is because I'm using Neo4jrb inside of a [Trailblazer-Operation](http://trailblazer.to/gems/operation/2.0/index.html). The trailblazer operation is broken up into discrete steps which are themselves written as separate methods. I want several of the steps wrapped in a transaction, but, without monkey patching the operation, I don't have the ability to execute some steps inside one transaction block.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that my problem has multiple solutions.

While it wasn't immediately apparent to me that this was the case, after a new transaction is created in Neo4jrb, any subsequent queries in that same session are automatically associated with the transaction as long as it remains open.

```
person = Person.find_by(id: person_id)

transaction = Neo4j::ActiveBase.new_transaction

one = person.update(name: 'New name')

two = person.update(number: 1)

transaction.close
```

In the above example, both `one` and `two` are committed as part of `transaction`. So this solves my problem.

Another solution to my problem, is that `trailblazer-operation` has a specific method for wrapping steps in a db transaction block, as documented on [Trailblazer's website](http://trailblazer.to/gems/operation/2.0/api.html#wrap).

```
step Wrap ->(*, &block) { Sequel.transaction do block.call end } {
  step Model( Song, :new )
  step Contract::Build( constant: MyContract )
  step Contract::Validate( )
  step Contract::Persist( method: :sync )
}
```

In the above example, all of the `step` methods inside `step Wrap` are called within the scope of the `Sequel.transaction` block.